# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator } even though I have one

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to have my application display my login activity when a user selects *"Add account"* in *"Accounts & Sync"* or wants to use the application and isn't logged in yet. I've followed the example [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) fairly closely, but can't get it to work and receive the following exception instead:

`No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator }`

My auth service contains:

```
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    IBinder ret = null;
    if (intent.getAction().equals(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT)){
        ret = getAuthenticator().getIBinder();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name=".auth.MyAuthService"
         android:exported="true" 
         android:process=":auth">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
               android:resource="@xml/authenticator" 
    />
```

My main activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT));
```

I've tried doing both:

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, CreazaAuthService.class);
startService(svc);
```

and:

```
bindService(new Intent(android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT), null, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

before the `startActivity()` call, but it still can't find an activity for that intent. If I try to add an account via accounts&sync my application crashes with the same `ActivityNotFoundException`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I've examined c99's last.fm app, which defines a custom action and uses intents based on that action rather than `android.accounts.AccountManager.ACTION_AUTHENTICATOR_INTENT`. Is that a better approach? Is there a way to make it work with Accounts & Sync?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your intent filter put `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Comment: If you're wondering _why_ this works, it's buried in the [Intents and Intent Filters documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). "Android treats all implicit intents passed to startActivity() as if they contained at least one category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (the CATEGORY_DEFAULT constant). Therefore, activities that are willing to receive implicit intents must include "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in their intent filters."